# For constrained device why AMQP client application is not good as like as MQTT client?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp, iot

We know MQTT is a light-weight protocol for constrained device. If I consider an AMQP client application for **a constrained device** instead of MQTT client, for what reason AMQP client application is not a good consideration?

For example, if I consider an AMQP client application instead of MQTT client application for **a Rasberry pi or from an Arduino device** what will be a killer factor for these constrained devices?

Is it the reason that AMQP client on constrained device will need more computation power than MQTT client ? or AMQP client library too big for constrained device?

Answer (score -1):

AMQP is not as light as MQTT, aside from not implementing the Pub/Sub pattern by itself. You can accomplish a Pub/Sub pattern in the broker but you would need to do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply. As you said ``AMQP is not as light as MQTT ``, I also know that MQTT is light-weight protocol. But if I want to use AMQP from a ``Rasberry pi`` or from a ``Arduino`` device what will be killer factor for AMQP protocol for these constrained device

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is not what I understand by "Constrained Devices", we are talking about quadra-core 1.2GHz procesor, 1GB RAM, etc. My answer was focused on more constrained devices as you didn't especify (you edited the OP afterwards). An AMQP server should be able to run on a RPi with little problem. NOTE: this does NOT mean that is the best solution, among all the IoT protocols, you should choose the one that best focus your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually, I am not developing a particlar application. I am discovering different case study for writing a paper with the different situation with the different case study. For example, for Air condition, wheelchair, refrigerator remote operation can be performed well with AMQP for reason. Everywhere on the internet I find very high-level protocol overview but not any example solution.